# What's an efficient way to have a Javascript table of functions?

Tags: javascript, function, optimization

In the code that follows I draw the dots on a die by having a table of functions that know how to draw the dots for any given die.

I'm worried, however, that these tables get recreated each and every time.  If I were in C++ I'd make them static, but that's of course not possible.  I'd like to know how to do it so that each time I call DrawDie it doesn't recreate the function tables.

Or is the compiler/parser/interpreter of a modern browser already smart enough that I don't have to worry about it?

```
// DrawDie
//
// Draws a die with 'dots' count of dots at a given location and size.  Dot     size is based on the die size.

function DrawDie(x, y, cx, cy, dots)
{
game.context.drawImage(game.getImage('Images/RedDie.png'), x, y, cx, cy);
var dotRadius  = cx / 10;
var dotSpacing = cx / 8 + dotRadius;
var centerX    = x + cx / 2;
var centerY    = y + cy / 2;

function Center()       { DrawCircle(centerX,              centerY,              dotRadius); };
function TopLeft()      { DrawCircle(centerX - dotSpacing, centerY - dotSpacing, dotRadius); };
function TopCenter()    { DrawCircle(centerX,              centerY - dotSpacing, dotRadius); };
function TopRight()     { DrawCircle(centerX + dotSpacing, centerY - dotSpacing, dotRadius); };
function MiddleLeft()   { DrawCircle(centerX - dotSpacing, centerY,              dotRadius)  };
function MiddleRight()  { DrawCircle(centerX + dotSpacing, centerY,              dotRadius)  };
function BottomLeft()   { DrawCircle(centerX - dotSpacing, centerY + dotSpacing, dotRadius); };
function BottomCenter() { DrawCircle(centerX,              centerY + dotSpacing, dotRadius); };
function BottomRight()  { DrawCircle(centerX + dotSpacing, centerY + dotSpacing, dotRadius); };

dieDrawingFunctions =
[
    [],                                                                                                     // 0
    [Center],                                                                                               // 1
    [TopLeft, BottomRight],                                                                                 // 2
    [Center, TopLeft, BottomRight],                                                                         // 3
    [TopLeft, TopRight, BottomLeft, BottomRight],                                                           // 4
    [TopLeft, TopRight, BottomLeft, BottomRight, Center],                                                   // 5
    [TopLeft, TopCenter, TopRight, BottomLeft, BottomCenter, BottomRight],                                  // 6
    [TopLeft, TopCenter, TopRight, BottomLeft, BottomCenter, BottomRight, Center],                          // 7
    [TopLeft, TopCenter, TopRight, BottomLeft, BottomCenter, BottomRight, MiddleLeft, MiddleRight],         // 8
    [TopLeft, TopCenter, TopRight, BottomLeft, BottomCenter, BottomRight, MiddleLeft, MiddleRight, Center], // 9
];

for (var i = 0; i < dieDrawingFunctions[dots].length; i++)
    dieDrawingFunctions[dots][i]();
```

}

Comment: *"If I were in C++ I'd make them static, but that's of course not possible."* Um...why not?

Comment: *"Or is the compiler/parser/interpreter of a modern browser already smart enough that I don't have to worry about it?"* Probably. Why don't you worry about it if/when you find a real problem using them? Premature optimization is usually a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid recreating those functions each time. Whether it's necessary/beneficial is another question, but you can:

```
function Center(centerX, centerY, dotRadius, dotSpacing)       { DrawCircle(centerX,              centerY,              dotRadius); };
function TopLeft(centerX, centerY, dotRadius, dotSpacing)      { DrawCircle(centerX - dotSpacing, centerY - dotSpacing, dotRadius); };
function TopCenter(centerX, centerY, dotRadius, dotSpacing)    { DrawCircle(centerX,              centerY - dotSpacing, dotRadius); };
function TopRight(centerX, centerY, dotRadius, dotSpacing)     { DrawCircle(centerX + dotSpacing, centerY - dotSpacing, dotRadius); };
function MiddleLeft(centerX, centerY, dotRadius, dotSpacing)   { DrawCircle(centerX - dotSpacing, centerY,              dotRadius)  };
function MiddleRight(centerX, centerY, dotRadius, dotSpacing)  { DrawCircle(centerX + dotSpacing, centerY,              dotRadius)  };
function BottomLeft(centerX, centerY, dotRadius, dotSpacing)   { DrawCircle(centerX - dotSpacing, centerY + dotSpacing, dotRadius); };
function BottomCenter(centerX, centerY, dotRadius, dotSpacing) { DrawCircle(centerX,              centerY + dotSpacing, dotRadius); };
function BottomRight(centerX, centerY, dotRadius, dotSpacing)  { DrawCircle(centerX + dotSpacing, centerY + dotSpacing, dotRadius); };
var dieDrawingFunctions = [
    [],                                                                                                     // 0
    [Center],                                                                                               // 1
    [TopLeft, BottomRight],                                                                                 // 2
    [Center, TopLeft, BottomRight],                                                                         // 3
    [TopLeft, TopRight, BottomLeft, BottomRight],                                                           // 4
    [TopLeft, TopRight, BottomLeft, BottomRight, Center],                                                   // 5
    [TopLeft, TopCenter, TopRight, BottomLeft, BottomCenter, BottomRight],                                  // 6
    [TopLeft, TopCenter, TopRight, BottomLeft, BottomCenter, BottomRight, Center],                          // 7
    [TopLeft, TopCenter, TopRight, BottomLeft, BottomCenter, BottomRight, MiddleLeft, MiddleRight],         // 8
    [TopLeft, TopCenter, TopRight, BottomLeft, BottomCenter, BottomRight, MiddleLeft, MiddleRight, Center], // 9
];

function DrawDie(x, y, cx, cy, dots)
{
    game.context.drawImage(game.getImage('Images/RedDie.png'), x, y, cx, cy);
    var dotRadius  = cx / 10;
    var dotSpacing = cx / 8 + dotRadius;
    var centerX    = x + cx / 2;
    var centerY    = y + cy / 2;

    for (var i = 0; i < dieDrawingFunctions[dots].length; i++) {
        dieDrawingFunctions[dots][i](centerX, centerY, dotRadius, dotSpacing);
    }
}
```

---

Side note: Your original code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a link to a post on my anemic little blog)* because you didn't declare your `dieDrawingFunctions` variable, so assigning to it created a global. I recommend using strict mode, which makes that an error, bringing it to your attention so you can fix it.